# How to simplify "render_to_string" in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, render, render-to-string

To render a partial in Rails 3 I do:

```
render 'my_partial', :my_object => my_value
```

To get partial's result as string I do:

```
render_to_string(:partial => 'my_partial', :layout => false, 
                 :locals => {:my_object => my_value})
```

Is this possible to write the last one shorter ? (e.g. to omit `:partial` or `:locals` like I do with `render`) (I tried, but get errors...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it could get any shorter, [Ref](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string).  If you feel it's too long you could hide it in a helper method, and just pass the various params?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you could do something like

```
 render_to_body "path_to_file"
```

and it skips layout but still you have to use instance variables inside your partial.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add your own method to `ApplicationController` and make it available as a helper method if you need to use it in views.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a Mailer for that. And then do.

MyMailer.my_method.body.encoded.
You can use helpers this way too.

Comment: It seems to be very hackety.